# Javascript Converter Coding Error ~ Showing Bug

Tags: javascript, html

the converter is not showing up an answer when I input value into the forms. It shows up pop-up alert "You must enter a number between 32 and 40"  ~Thanks

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bra Size to Chest Size Converter - CM</TITLE>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext, form)
        {
            var A = BratoNum(Btext);
            var B = parseFloat(CuptoNum(Btext));
            form.Answer.value = A + B;
        }


        function ClearForm(form)
        {
            form.input_A.value = "";
            form.input_B.value = "";
            form.Answer.value = "";
        }

        function BratoNum(str)
        {
            switch(str.toUpperCase()) {
                case "32": return 70;
                case "34": return 75;
                case "36": return 80;
                case "38": return 85;
                case "40": return 90;
                default:  alert('You must enter a number between 32 and 40!');
                return 'X';
            }
        }

        function CuptoNum(str)
        {
            switch(str.toUpperCase()) {
                case "A": return 4;
                case "B": return 5;
                case "C": return 6;
                case "D": return 7;
                case "E": return 8;
                case "F": return 9;
                default:  alert('You must enter a letter between A and F!');
                return 'X';
            }
        }

// end of JavaScript functions -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

    <P><FONT SIZE="+2">Bra Size to Chest Size Converter</FONT></P>

    <FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
    <P>Enter Bra Size: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=8></P>

    <P>Enter Cup Size: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=8></P>

    <P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Get Chest Size" name="AddButton" onClick="CalculateSum(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form)"></P>

    <P>Your Chest Size is <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=8> inch</P>
    <P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)"></P>
    </FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: put your code in `<pre><code>` tags

Comment: What error/bug are you seeing? Please give us some more info to make it easier to help you.

Comment: the converter is not showing up an answer when I input the forms Thanks~

Comment: see the answer below, its working fine now.

Comment: maybe adding `bra size` as a tag would get more views? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var A = BratoNum(Atext);
```

You are passing `Btext` instead!

Answer (score 1):

> Actually you are passing invalid
>   argument to BratoNum function. That is
>   why it always going into default case'

```
var A = BratoNum(Atext);
// Here I have changed the argument , which you suppose to pass.
```

;